# How to hide default zero from amount field in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to show placeholder value in text box if Model Cost value is '0', but it's showing default '0'. What is incorrect in the following code?

```
<div class="leftflotdiv">
     @if (Model.SkillSets[j].Cost > 0)
     {
         @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SkillSets[j].Cost, new { @class = "input_newmainbg", placeholder = "Cost per hour", Value = Model.SkillSets[j].Cost })
     }
     else
     { 
         @Model.SkillSets[j].Cost
         @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SkillSets[j].Cost, new { @class = "input_newmainbg", placeholder = "Cost per hour" })
     }
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Make the name of the field according to your model field to bind the input field to the model property.

```
  <input type="text" name='SkillSets[@j].Cost' placeholder="Cost per hour" class = "input_newmainbg" />
```

Comment: thank you so much for helping me on this. it worked for me. great efforts